# Можно ли вызвать super() без аргументов? JS

Tags: javascript, классы

У меня есть класс который инициализирует popUp:

```
class PopUp {
    constructor() {
        // popUp
        this.container = document.querySelector('.popup');
        // forms
        this.popUpForm = document.querySelector('.popup__content');
        this.form = document.querySelector('.popup__form');
        this.inputName = document.querySelector('.popup__input_type_name');      
        this.inputAbout = document.querySelector('.popup__input_type_about');
        this.popUpTitle = document.querySelector('.popup__title');
        this.popUpButton = document.querySelector('.popup__button');
        this.submit = document.getElementById('submit');
        // closeButton
        this.closeButton = document.querySelector('.popup__close');

        // добавляю EventListener
        this.setEventListener();
    }
```

От него строятся 2 формы одна для редактирования профиля, другая для добавления картинок на страницу (да немного заморочено но так вышло)

вот пример:

```
class PopupCard extends PopUp {
    constructor() {
        super();
    }

    open() {
        // этот метод создает форму "Новое место"
        this.container.classList.add('popup_is-opened');
        this.popUpButton.classList.add('popup__button_content');
        // так как шаблон формы однин, add я сбрасываю
        this.form.reset();
        // специализация формы
        this.popUpTitle.textContent = 'Новое место';
        this.inputName.placeholder = 'Название';                    
        this.inputAbout.placeholder = 'Ссылка на картинку';     
        this.popUpButton.textContent = '+';
        // атрибуты проверки валидности формы
        this.inputName.setAttribute('minlength', '2');                     
        this.inputName.setAttribute('maxlength', '30');                    
        this.inputAbout.setAttribute('type', 'url');                       
        // атрибут name
        this.addAttr(event);
    }
}

class PopupProfile extends PopUp {
    constructor() {
        super();
    }

    open() {
        // этот метод создает форму "Редактировать профиль"
        this.container.classList.add('popup_is-opened');
        this.popUpButton.classList.add('popup__button_edit');
        this.popUpButton.classList.add('popup__button_valid');
        // специализация формы
        this.popUpTitle.textContent = 'Редактировать профиль';
        this.inputName.placeholder = 'Имя';                  
        this.inputAbout.placeholder = 'О себе';                   
        this.popUpButton.textContent = 'Сохранить';
        // задаю input начения по умолчанию
        userInfo.setUserInfo();
        // атрибуты проверки валидности формы
        this.inputName.setAttribute('minlength', '2');                     
        this.inputName.setAttribute('maxlength', '30');
        this.inputAbout.setAttribute('minlength', '2');                     
        this.inputAbout.setAttribute('maxlength', '30');
        // атрибут name
        this.addAttr(event);
    }
}
```

Вопрос: можно ли так использовать super() или ему обязательно нужно передать аргументы?

```
class PopupCard extends PopUp {
    constructor() {
        super();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Во-первых, если функция/метод/конструктор объявлены без параметров и не ожидают никаких параметров, то их и надо вызывать без параметров.

Во-вторых, в JavaScript любая функция может быть вызвана без параметров. И уже от самой функции зависит, как она с этим справится.

И в-третьих - от @AlexeyTen, если единственное, что делает конструктор, это вызывает `super`, никак не изменяя параметры, то его (конструктор) можно просто не писать.

Comment: Я бы ещё добавил в-третьих, если единственное что делает конструктор это вызывает super никак не изменяя параметры, то его (конструктор) можно просто не писать